# Login user after registration programmatically

Tags: login, user-registration, wp-login-form, remote-login

I have setup some process that should register a new user and login the new user right after registration.
This is my function for registration:

```
    add_filter('the_content', 'registeration_submit_user');

function registeration_submit_user($content) {
    // Get the current post
    global $post;
    // Get the value of the slug
    $page_slug = $post->post_name;
    // Checks is the current page is the custom registration page and it has a $_POST value
    if ($page_slug === "registration" && $_POST['nons_ipt'] === 'registeration_submit_user') {
        // Hendle the registration
        $user_email = 'yos@sjdj.com';
        $arr = explode("@", $user_email, 2);
        $user_name = $arr[0];
        $user_id = username_exists($user_name);
        if (!$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false) {
            $random_password = wp_generate_password($length = 12, $include_standard_special_chars = false);
            $user_id = wp_create_user($user_name, $random_password, $user_email);
        } else {
            $random_password = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.' . $response);
        }
        return $random_password;
    } else {
        // Rest of pages
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to login the user right after wp_create_user function. 
I tried to do this with the following code:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $user_name;
$creds['user_password'] = $random_password;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) )
  echo $user->get_error_message();
```

But the problem is that i get this message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at...

What is the best way to make this happen?

Comment: The error tells you the problem- you have to log someone in before any output is sent to the browser.

Comment: That is why i am asking, because i would like to login right after registration. Maybe I can redirect to some page? but even then, how i can implement login in custom page? it should be in the init and i do not know the page id in the init stage.

Comment: what hooks are you using?... can you complete the code up to hooks and related functions please.

Comment: I have update the code above

Comment: if your POST fields are sufficiently unique, I don't see why you have to know it's the registration page to process a registration, anywhere between `init` and `template_redirect` would work.

Comment: `the_content` hook is your problem. you'll really get those errors... best to use `template_redirect` as mentioned above me.

Comment: Great! but how do i pass parameters with template_redirect?